# Representing IP address range with mask

Tags: networking, ip, netmask

Given an IP address range, is there an algorithm for turning it into a set of pairs in the form of (ip,mask) that covers all range?

Comment: A set of pairs or only one pair (ip,mask)?
Can you add an example?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I'll give an example:
For the range 192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255 the algorithm will return {(192.168.0.0,255.255.0.0)}.
Of course this is a simple example and the problem starts with ranges that can not be covered with a single (ip,mask) pair.
Moreover, the solution is required to be minimal.

Comment: Then you should define the minimum subnet lenght for different pairs. For example 192.168.0.100 and 193.168.0.100 both belong to the pair (192.0.0.0, 254.0.0.0) but you probably want to different pairs (192.0.0.0, 255.0.0.0) and (193.0.0.0, 255.0.0.0). Please add this information to your question.

Comment: There is a section in [Part 2 of this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53995/8499) for how to find a common network for multiple addresses.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just a simple IP, you can find your S.N. mask, the range of IPs of your network, your subnet IP, and its broadcast IP. All the IPs have the same S.N. mask. So, the algorithm is like this: 

`for i="S.N. IP + 1" to i="Broadcast IP - 1" 
createPair (i,S.N. mask);`
That's all!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but please see my comment above.

Comment: So, the input of your algorithm is a range of IPs and the output is the pair (Network ID, S.N. mask). That's what I meant with the comment above but anyway here it is a CISCO tutorial that can help you to build the algorithm.[CISCO](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/54474-analyzing-existing-subnets-faster-magic-number-method) It teaches you how to retrieve some information by having only an IP range. When the ranges could not be covered by a single IP, this means that there are different networks, and you have to apply the algorithm for each one of them.